# Compare array with sorted Array, pick first element

Tags: arrays, lodash

The setup is the following :

```
targets = ['green','orange','red'];  //targets are in order of priority
sources = ['redalert','blackadder','greenlantern'];
```

I am trying to make a function that returns the one source element which contains the highest priority target string. In this case, it would be 'greenlantern', as it contains the string 'green', which has higher priority than 'red' found in 'redalert'.

I have done it already using for loops and temp arrays, but I know these manipulations aren't my forte, and my real-life arrays are way larger, so I'd like to optimize execution. I have tried with Lodash too, but can't figure out how to do it all in one step. Is it possible?

The way I see it, it has to :

- `for each target, loop through sources, if source elem matches target elem, break and return.`

but I'm sure there's a better way.

Comment: Can the source contain exactly one target or any amount? So you could also have "blue wave" or "red-green kilt"?

Comment: any amount. if I get more than one sources containg the highest priority source, I'll just pick the first one. ('greenlantern','greenkilt')

Comment: Ok that makes it easier, although I still see no fast way if you just pass in those 2 arrays to the function, even if target is constant... sources can't be sorted before I guess, otherwise the function would not be needed. So your algorithm seems to be the best approach!

Comment: and yet, I'm somehow disappointed :) Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I see you accepted an answer, it is a nice example, but performancewise your approach is better and the code is not longer.

Comment: that's true, I was rewarding the style more than anything :) I hate to have nested for loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another lodash approach that uses [reduce()](https://lodash.com/docs#reduce) instead of [sortBy()](https://lodash.com/docs#sortBy):

```
_.reduce(targets, function(result, target) {
    return result.concat(_.filter(sources, function(source) {
        return _.includes(source, target);
    }));
}, []);
```

Since `targets` is already in order, you can iterate over it and build the result in the same order. You use `reduce()` because you're building a result iteratively, that isn't a direct mapping.

Inside the reduce callback, you can `concat()` results by using [filter()](https://lodash.com/docs#filter) and [includes()](https://lodash.com/docs#includes) to find the appropriate `sources`.

---

This gets you the *sorted array*, but it's also doing a lot of unnecessary work if you only want the first `source` that corresponds to the first `target`:

```
_.find(sources, _.ary(_.partialRight(_.includes, _.first(targets)), 1));
```

Or, if you prefer not to compose callback functions:

```
_.find(sources, function(item) {
    return _.includes(item, _.first(targets));
});
```

Essentially, [find()](https://lodash.com/docs#find) will only iterate over the `sources` collection till there's a match. The [first()](https://lodash.com/docs#first) function gets you the first `target` to look for.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping it very simple:

```
var sortedSources = _.sortBy(sources, function(source){
  var rank = 0
  while(rank < targets.length){
    if(source.indexOf(targets[rank]) > -1){
      break
    }else{
      rank++
    }
  }
  return rank
})
```

Sources are now sorted by target priority, thus `sortedSources[0]` is your man.